# UndefinedVariableError when converting .py file includes lines like df.query("foo=@bar") to .pyd file

Tags: python, pandas, cython

I've never used Cython but I need to encrypt my source code.

My questions is, how could I convert python files which include lines like `df.query("foo=@bar")` to Cython.

How to replicate this error:

foo.py

```
import pandas as pd
bar=1
df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5],columns=['test'])
print(df.query("test==@bar"))
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [
    Extension("sample_code",  ["foo.py"]),
]

setup(
    name = 'My Program',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

then, run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

```
from sample_code import foo
```

and I got error:`pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: local variable 'bar' is not defined`

Comment: That's not surprising.  `query` has to an `eval` (or equivalent`) to translate the string "test==@bar" into something it can execute.  Without getting into the details, that will be hard, if not impossible, to render in compiled code.

Comment: do you import `foo` to other file ? Then you may need `foo.bar`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @hapulj Thanks for your explaination. I appreciate it.

Comment: @furas That would cost ~100 lines lol so I only gave a small demo to replicate this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @hpaulj says in the comments: `@bar` isn't going to work because it uses Python introspection mechanisms to look up the dictionary of the caller. Cython doesn't generate the information.

Based on [the documentation for `DataFrame.Eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval) you can pass the keyword arguments `locals_dict` or `globals_dict`. So you could do either:

```
df.query("test==@bar", locals_dict={'bar': bar})
```

or

```
df.query("test==@bar", locals_dict=locals())
```

---

It's worth emphasising that simply putting this in a Cython file offers no performance advantages. The performance will be determined by the performance of Pandas, and the fact that you've compiled the file that calls Pandas makes no difference at all.

It also offers limited "encryption" advantages in your case - the string `"test==@bar"` will definitely be findable in your compiled Cython file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David. I appreciate your help and your kindly suggestions. I understand those strings would keep unchanged even in .exe/pyd files. In fact, this simple "encryption" make it easier to write a new program other than decompile mine. And that's all I need.